# custom SQL query not getting all the rows

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `users_search_activity` (
  `ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `search_keywords` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users_search_activity`
--

INSERT INTO `users_search_activity` (`ID`, `user_id`, `country_id`, `search_keywords`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 132, 2, 'xavie', '2021-07-13 08:20:37'),
(2, 132, 6, 'xavier', '2021-07-13 08:21:38'),
(3, 132, 5, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 08:21:39'),
(4, 132, 4, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 08:21:39'),
(5, 131, 9, 'xavier ins',  '2021-07-13 08:22:12'),
(6, 132, 7, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 08:22:25'),
(7, 132, 8, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:43'),
(8, 132, 6, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:45'),
(9, 132, 4, 'xavier insa', '2021-07-13 09:24:47'),
(10, 131, 5, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:54'),
(11, 132, 3, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:54'),
(12, 132, 2, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:58'),
(13, 132, 9, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:59'),
(14, 132, 3, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:25:00'),
(15, 132, 4, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:25:02'),
(16, 132, 5, 'inst', '2021-07-13 09:58:20'),
(17, 132, 9, 'inst', '2021-07-04 09:58:25'),
(18, 132, 100, 'inst', '2021-07-07 09:58:25'),
(19, 132, 1, 'inst', '2021-07-11 09:58:26'),
(20, 132, 4, 'inst', '2021-07-12 09:58:26'),
(21, 1, 12, 'University Business Academy in Novi Sad', '2021-07-14 10:16:33');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `users_search_activity`
--
ALTER TABLE `users_search_activity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users_search_activity`
--
ALTER TABLE `users_search_activity`
  MODIFY `ID` bigint(21) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=21;
COMMIT;
```

Here I want to get the count of users based on country_id and date. So to achieve that I have made  sql query like this

```
SELECT  COUNT(user_id) as count, date(date) as date , country_id
    FROM  users_search_activity
    WHERE  country_id != ""
    GROUP BY  country_id
    ORDER BY  date DESC
```

Up to some extent its working fine but the issue is its not getting the row for `2021-07-12` date.

Here is the output what I am getting

```
count   date        country_id
1       2021-07-14  12
3       2021-07-13  5
4       2021-07-13  4
3       2021-07-13  9
1       2021-07-13  7
1       2021-07-13  8
2       2021-07-13  3
2       2021-07-13  2
2       2021-07-13  6
1       2021-07-11  1
1       2021-07-07  100
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Any suggestions and advice would be really appreciable.

**FYI:** I am using MySQL 5.7

Comment: The query is invalid. You are in MySQL's notorious cheat mode. Please use `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` to get out if this. You are grouping by country, this gives you one row per country. But you select the country's date. Does each country really have exactly one date in the table? This sounds unlikely. You can't access *the* date; you can select the maximum date or the minimum date or another date you pick by some rule. You cannot order by date either for the same reason. What MySQL does in cheat mode, is convert your date to `ANY_VALUE(date)` silently.

Comment: If you want to count users per country and date, then group by country and date. "per x and y" translates to `GROUP BY x, y` in SQL.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e925b7e001831e990990cc4b4d36e04c All I have done is added date(date), in the group by clause simmilar to what @ThorstenKettner mentioned in his second comment... And your date is in the result

Comment: @VBoka for some reason it works not if I use date https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/46, maybe because it is a reserved word, but if i treat as an alias it gives the correct results, as I posted in the answer

Comment: On a side note: MySQL 5.7 is quite old and there have been great features added in MySQL 8. You may want to consider an upgrade.